# MVC.Net site is throwing a 404 error for a resource/page that isn't being called

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404

Ok, this one is killing me. It makes no sense at all... I've setup a simple MVC.Net project. Everything appears to work fine. I get the typical 404 errors, and wanted to change that so I started looking into that... That got me poking around in the Application_Error method in the global.asax. It all appears to work as I would expect.

Here's the problem. I put the following line of code (just this line) in the Application_Error method and made a breakpoint to see what the error traffic was like so I could test things, etc.

```
Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
```

I'm running the project in debug, and it comes back with an HttpException with an error code 404

> The controller for path
>   '/Content/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js'
>   was not found or does not implement
>   IController.

So far nothing too strange, right? So, I did a search for this offending call. I used the Visual Studio Find function and searched **Entire Solution** for /Content/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js. There were no calls to this file. I searched for jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js and found all the expected calls to that file which look for it in the /Scripts/ directory.

In the /Content/ directory I have my .css files, and some images in the Images subdirectory...

I'm hoping there is just something strange that I don't know about with MVC.Net that you guys have already figured out that causes this quirkiness. It just makes no sense... I could see getting the 404 if there was a call to that file, but there isn't...

Any guidance on even some troubleshooting ideas would be helpful at this point. I'm stumped...

Thanks guys!

Comment: Did you try searching in Views/Shared/site.master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a suggestion to help you debug: Download Fiddler and check the actually HTTP requests being made. Note: When debugging using localhost, make a new hosts entry and point 127.0.0.1 to some other name, otherwise Fiddler won't track the requests.

Comment: Ok... I just ran the fiddler trace (good suggestion). The call wasn't being made... Here's the fun part, I redid it with the breakpoint again, and the call isn't being made this time... I swear, I think my computer knows that these are my first few forum posts on Overflow, and it's trying to make me look stupid... Gonna go to sleep and hang my head in shame again... FWIW, before writing I did restart VS multiple times, and killed caches too... No idea, man..

Comment: Here's a bit wild idea: Create file named 'jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js' in your /Content folder which is actually a view (with some basic markup in it). See if it gets served up.